# Xpath/xQuery difference in months

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to get the difference between two dates in months for an xPath.

I have no problems getting it in days (1127)

```
days-from-duration(xs:date('2012-06-17')-xs:date('2009-05-17'))
```

When I try doing it in months I get 0

```
 months-from-duration(xs:date('2012-06-17')-xs:date('2009-05-17'))
```

I did notice that this comes back as days only ("P1126D") so that maybe the problem just not sure how to fix it.

```
 xs:date('2012-06-17')-xs:date('2009-05-17')
```

Thanks for any help!

So the best thing I can seem to do is manually calculate it.

```
(year-from-date(xs:date('2012-06-17')) - year-from-date(xs:date('2012-05-18')))*12 + month-from-date(xs:date('2012-06-17')) -month-from-date(xs:date('2012-05-18')) + (if (day-from-date(xs:date('2012-06-17'))  < day-from-date(xs:date('2012-05-18')) ) then -1 else 0)
```

Comment: Hmm. You *can* divide by durations, so you could divide by a one-month duration...

Comment: ...except that only a yearMonthDuration *has* a duration field, and those don't have days.

Comment: BTW -- if you're going to add an edit that has an impact on an answer's relevance, please clearly mark it as such; when you subsume an answer's information into your question, that makes it look like the answer wasn't helpful. (And usually, comments on an answer are better in that case).

Answer (score 2):

This function was not included in the spec because we couldn't agree semantics for it. We heard arguments that the difference between 31 March 2015 and 30 Sept 2015 was six months, and arguments that it was five months. (Advice: negative differences seem to be even more problematic than positive differences.) You can easily find that a date plus 6 months minus 6 months is not the date where you started. You'll have to define what you think the answer should be, and implement it using lower-level facilities such as month-from-date and year-from-date.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `days-from-duration` returns the `days` **field** -- not the number of days the duration includes. Likewise for months and years.

Now, you can divide by days, but not by months (since months have uneven boundaries):

```
(: arg1 here is a dayTimeDuration, which can't be easily converted to a yearMonthDuration :)
let $arg1 := xs:date('2012-06-17')-xs:date('2009-05-17')
return xs:dayTimeDuration($arg1) div xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
```